# Bus arrival density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

```
Fred lives in Blissville, where buses always arrive exactly on time, with the time
between successive buses fixed at 10 minutes. Having lost his watch, he arrives at
the bus stop at a random time (assume that buses run 24 hours a day, and that the
time that Fred arrives is uniformly random on a particular day).

 **What is the distribution of how long Fred has to wait for the next bus? What is
the average time that Fred has to wait, and what is the density function (PDF) or his waiting time till the next bus?
```

So the answer is:
$E[X] = 5$
and the PDF is $\frac{1}{10}$.

Can you explain me why?
Why do I need to get the average between 0 and 10 for the $E[X]$ and why the pdf is $\frac{1}{10}$?

I mean I want to understand the inside of the calculation.. the lambda here is 1/10 but other than that.. I know that PDF is not just the lambda so how can be it 1/10?

Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3958655/pdf-probability-density-function/3960141#3960141

Comment: Thanks @AmaanM. But why the answer is $\frac{1}{10}$ and not lets say ${\lambda e}^{\lambda x}$ ?

Comment: We don't know when the last bus came or when the next one is coming, so it's generally an equally likely amount of time that Fred will have to wait anywhere between 0 and 10. It's a bit like rolling dice - all six faces are equally likely, so each outcome has a probability of 1/6. Same idea, except the amount of time Fred has to wait is on a continuous support, not discrete - the set of real numbers between 0 and 10. That's how we get to the shape, with f(x) = 1/10. The probabilities then come from integrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buses arrive always on time every 10' thus the distribution is uniform in $[0;10]$
The density of a continuous uniform is

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}=\frac{1}{10-0}=\frac{1}{10}$$

Its expectation ( the average time he has to wait) is

$$E(X)=\frac{a+b}{2}=\frac{0+10}{2}=5$$

Comment: Thank you. About the density - why it's not something in the from of ${\lambda e}^{\lambda x}$ ?

Comment: @BenTyler because the text is clearly saying you that the correct model is an uniform one (the time that Fred arrives is uniformly random ...). The one you showed is an exponential model